# How to solve java.io.FileNotFoundException with jQuery file upload and Spring-boot

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a file and save the file name to the database. I have add the CommonsMultipartResolver dependency and defined the CommonsMultipartResolver bean in my Spring configuration.Done all i can but i am still getting java.io.FileNotFoundException error.

Error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/0q/_ll9y13s5rn7cym4_9l6lb0c0000gn/T/tomcat.2486137170479409904.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_2793f497_312d_401f_91e7_d2bc29ddfec6_00000001.tmp (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:188) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getBytes(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:291) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:664) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
```

Config

```
 @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver()
    {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver2() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile uploadfile, Picture picture, Principal principal) {
        User user = (User) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
        picture.setUser(user);
        try {
            // Crop the image (uploadfile is an object of type MultipartFile)
            BufferedImage croppedImage = cropImageSquare(uploadfile.getBytes());

            // Get the filename and build the local file path
            String filename = uploadfile.getOriginalFilename();
            String directory = "/Users/molayodecker/Sites/admissionsPortal/data";
            String filepath = Paths.get(directory, filename).toString();
            String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);

            // Save the file locally
            File outPutFile = new File(filepath);
            ImageIO.write(croppedImage, ext, outPutFile);
            //stream.write(uploadfile.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        pictureService.save(picture, uploadfile);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    } // method uploadFile
```

Form

```
<form  id="upload-file-input" th:action="@{/uploadFile}" method="post" th:object="${picture}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline inline new-item">
<input type="file" id="file" name="uploadfile" />
<span class="placeholder" data-placeholder="Choose an image...">Choose an image...</span>
<label for="file" class="button">Browse</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

JS File

```
var $formUploader = $("#upload-file-input");
  $formUploader.on("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //var data = new FormData(this);
   var data={};
   $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field){
     data[field.name] = field.value;
   });
   $.ajax({
           //dataType: 'json',
           url: $formUploader.prop('action'),
           type: "POST",
           //data: new FormData($("#upload-file-input")[0]),
           data: data,
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
             // Handle upload success
             $("#upload-file-message").text("File succesfully uploaded");
           },
           error: function () {
             // Handle upload error
             $("#upload-file-message").text("File not uploaded (File might be big, size needed.)");
           }
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  CSRF protection in your Spring application is enabled.
you should add _csrf_header ,_csrf with your ajax request
e.g:

```
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"); 
$.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        -----
    }
}
```

Also you can disable csrf _csrf_header ->

```
@Configuration
public class App extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am get an error `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` i don't know why

Comment: it worked but now i am getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException error

Comment: please add the full stack trace